# Saxon (XSLT 2.*) transforms but can not debug .xsl

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am facing a problem debugging a xslt transformation using Saxon (XSLT 2.*). So when I start transformation, everything passes well (no errors), but when I start a debug session (using the same processor) I get error on the first `step into` command.

This is the .xsl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:import href="../Product/templates.xsl"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:variable name="space" select="'&#32;'"/>

    <xsl:template name="root" match="/">R
        <xsl:call-template name="test-plan"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="test-plan">
    <test-plan>

        <xsl:variable name="report">
            <xsl:call-template name="test-suite-1"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="start-time" select="current-dateTime()"/>

               <xsl:copy-of select="$report"/>

        <xsl:variable name="end-time" select="current-dateTime()"/>

        <report start="{$start-time}" end="{$end-time}">
            <xsl:value-of select="55"/>
        </report>
    </test-plan>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="test-suite-1">
            <xsl:call-template name="test-case-1"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="test-case-1">
        <xsl:variable name="prefix" select="translate('...', '.', $space)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="suffix" select="translate('..', '.', $space)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="text" select="'the_text'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="expectation" select="concat($prefix, $text, $suffix)"/>
        <test-case name="test-case-1">
            <xsl:call-template name="repeater">
                <xsl:with-param name="count" select="1000000"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </test-case>    
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

End this is the error:[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

The IDE I am using is a **Exchange XML Editor V 3.3.01**

Comment: Your sample says `version="1.0"`. And Saxon does not come with a debugger as far as I know so you need to explain in detail which tool or IDE you use with Saxon to do the debugging. Does that IDE or tool have no way to give you details about the "2 errors detected"?

Comment: I have edited my original post. The IDE has three processors to be used: Xalan, Saxon(XSLT 1.*) and  Saxon(XSLT 2.*). Only Saxon(XSLT 2.*) can do transformations, but none of them can do debugging with **this specific file**. With other files I have had no problems debugging. This is the first time I face problem debugging.

Comment: I'm afraid that (as the author of Saxon) I know nothing about the Exchange XML Editor. You will have to contact them for support. The error message "Failed to compile stylesheet. 2 errors detected" comes from Saxon, and means that 2 errors have been reported to the application (that is, the IDE); I would have expected the IDE to display these errors somewhere.